# Adobe applications - Case-sensitive volumes not supported

Tags: macbook-pro

I need someone to put this together in the most fool-proof way possible.

I recently reinstalled the OS on my Macbook Air 2014 (Yosemite) as I had a ton of useless files as it was acting super duper slow so now that I want to install Photoshop, Illustrator and InDesign (which my entire life depends on as I'm a design student) it gives me an error: 
Installation on case-sensitive volumes is not supported. Please choose a different volume for installation.

I know this topic has been discussed before but tbh I didn't understand a thing going through them lol. So I know there is this thing called iPartition but I currently don't want to spend any money on apps and am more than happy to reboot my entire Macbook or pick a different OS if that helps.

Any thoughts?

Comment: By "reboot" I assume you mean "reinstall"?

Comment: Wel what I did was that I cleared everything on the Disk Utility page and re-installed Yosemite

Comment: @MIAMORT When you did that, you must have re-created the disk as case-sensitive. Redo this, but select the non case-sensitive format this time. A lot of software will refuse to install on case-sensitive volumes, so you're in for a bag of hurt in the future if you keep OS X installed in this way.

Comment: Sounds like a reinstall. Part of how this site works is making sure we use clear shared language. Change your question to be clear you reinstalled the system, as reboot is jargon that means something different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what Adobe has to say about this [error](https://helpx.adobe.com/creative-suite/kb/error-case-sensitive-drives-supported.html).

It means you have to reinstall OS X.

[image]
Reformat and Choose OS X Extended (Journaled) as in the image above.

Comment: fuck. can't even do it from another partition.

Comment: That's just great user experience (for some money per month), software for editing pictures requires you to reformat your harddrive.

Comment: omfg, this is ridiculous. good example of so bad software:  adobe xd...

Answer (score 0):

Most people never need the case sensitive option. It should have been deselected for you in install, and you selected it.

Don't do this. If you take the defaults it gives you, you will get what you want.